# Are there actually any "cameras, drones, and alarms" for me to be concerned about at Redwood-Watts?

Tags: dex

Decker says, before the infiltration, that I have to [watch for cameras, drones, and alarms](https://youtu.be/wm7-LHdQB94?t=339), even though Richard hacked in and is keeping me safe.

I therefore tried taking down everyone I could and avoided being spotted by the armored security, but was that really necessary? Could I have just went in, shotgun blazing, fists of fury, nanites keeping me alive and just decking everyone without any concern about noise, and it would've been fine?

I've only been into the Server Room when the *first* alarms of the facility started happening, before I decided to restart and keep Ellie alive.